# How to access last local notification if the user ignored the last alert on ios?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

My app is in background, and the notification alert did show correctly and the badge number was increased by 1.
IF the user taps on the alert everything works fine and the delegate `didReceiveLocalNotification` is called.

But the user ignored the alert.
After a while when the user open my app again, the only delegate called is `didBecomeActive`.
How can I do something (show a `UIAlertView` for example), based on the last ignored alert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS itself doesn't provide any method for that.

But you can simply do that:

1. While you are registering notification to iOS - write all notification data to a file.
2. On application start load notification file and all notification that expired (NSDate < now) - those are ignored notifications.
3. Before doing 2. you need to check if maybe someone came from a notification and delete it from your file.

It's kind of duplicating iOS notification management system which is not allowing to get a list of registered notification unfortunately.

Writing a notification to a file should be easy: it's already implementing NSCoding protocol.

Comment: lot of work for something that apple should make to be simple. thank's

Comment: this will work if the notification repeat interval is not set...what if the repeat interval is set to something say daily...how do i check the ignored uilocalnotification which appeared due to repeat interval??

Comment: If you know interval and you know how much time passed from setting it up, it should be possible to calculate that quite easily

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, if the notification is ignored, you can't recover it once you open the app again.

You'll need to check the service that pushed that notification to know if there's something new

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not a straight forward way to achieve it.

Possible workaround - If the user dismisses/ignored your push notification, your app could take a look at messages on your server and handle it the appropriate way.